# What's the visualization of $z=\sec\theta+i\cdot\csc\theta$ in complex-plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

What would be the graph of $z=\sec\theta+i\cdot\csc\theta$ in complex plane? Since $z=\cos\theta+i\cdot\sin\theta$ is a circle.

Comment: Where does this question come from? Why is it natural for you to consider this quantity? (please answer by editing the question, rather than in the comments).

Comment: Note that their real part $x$ and imaginary part $y$ satisfy $x^{-2}+y^{-2}=1$. Conversely, for every pair of numbers satisfying $a^{-2}+b^{-2}=1$, there is $\theta$ such that $a=\sec(\theta)$ and $b=\csc(\theta)$, because there $r=1/a$ and $s=1/b$ satisfy $r^2+s^2=1$ So, it ss the set of points $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ x^{-2}+y^{-2}=1\}$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I am just curious. Trying to imagine complex functions. I don't think this reason should be in the question.

Comment: @NamanJain Part of the "good question" etiquette is to provide some context. The question I asked you is natural and by answering it in the body of the question you save a lot of time for everyone who is going to read it.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You are right. I will consider it

Comment: If the question has a lot of unimportant clutter, I will have to spend time reading all that and weeding out what is actually the question. You will also have to spend time typing unimportant words. It is clear what is a waste of time and what isn't, and who is here to waste your time and who isn't. Your post is perfect. Question ... and there is your answer.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I actually want to visualise the graph.

Comment: To visualize you need to plot. Plotting could be done directly with the parametrization given, or one can use the implicit equation in my answer, and solve for one of the variables to obtain a parametrization that is algebraic instead. It looks like the graph has $4$ disjoint lines similar to hyperbolas.

Comment: There is also a way to get a parametrization by rational functions. This can be obtained using the [half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x=sec \theta$ adn $y=csc \theta $ you get $$\frac {1}{x^2} + \frac {1}{y^2}=1$$ or $$y=\pm \sqrt{\frac {x^2}{x^2-1}}$$

The graph consists of four branches with two vertical asymptotes at $x=\pm 1$ and two horizontal asymptotes at  $y=\pm 1$

Comment: Aren't there four branches? I guess it depends on what you mean by branch.

Comment: @Milten  Thanks for the comment.  I edited my answer accordingly.